# Yet another minishell pipeline in C

Tags: c, shell, pipeline

As many before me, I'm trying to implement a basic shell in C. Overall things are working nicely, and I'm now trying to add pipes and redirections.

I've read a lot about the `pipe()` function and have successfully written a side program to pipe a function's output into a second function's input.

Where I have trouble is when it comes to looping over an undetermined amount of functions.

Here's the last version of my function as well as the main I use to test it :

```
char        **g_env;

int         ft_pipeline(char **cmd, unsigned int pos)
{
    int     in;
    int     pfd[2];
    pid_t   pid;
    char    **cur_cmd;

    in = 0;
    while (cmd[pos])
    {
        if (pipe(pfd) != 0)
            return (1);
        close(pfd[0]);
        dup2(pfd[1], in);
        close(pfd[1]);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)
            return (2);
        if (pid == 0) //child
        {
            close(pfd[1]);
            dup2(pfd[0], 0);
            close(pfd[0]);
            cur_cmd = ft_strsplit_blank(cmd[pos]);
            execve(cur_cmd[0], cur_cmd, g_env);
        }
        wait(NULL);
        in = pfd[0];
        pos++;
    }
    return (0);
}

int         main(void)
{
    char    **cmd = ft_strsplit("/bin/ls -l /dev | /bin/grep std", '|');
    g_env = NULL;
    ft_pipeline(cmd, 0);
    return (0);
}
```

In this current form, ls is properly executed but written to stdout, and grep returns :

> /bin/grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor

This is the fifth time I rewrite my code, and I've tried to tweak it for a few days now. I've also read several other post here to try and grasp the logic behind this small program, to no avail.

I'd really like it if you could tell me where I'm making the mistake and how I could fix it.

Note : You will very likely find many ways to improve this code in its form. I know about it but that's something that I cannot do, in most cases. Although this is not homework, it is still something that I do for school (see it as a voluntary practice) and I have to respect standards in the way I write my code or the functions I use.

Comment: As your code is not complete it is hard to test in a debugger. But what do you expect for input in the variable pos to the function ft_pipeline? Was it really your intention to increase that input variable in the loop?

Comment: **1** For `N` commands you need `N-1` `pipe`s. **2** Left standard output goes to the pipe, so you need to `dup2` your `pipefd[1]` *to `1`* for the left process. Right standard input goes to the pipe, so you need to `dup2` your `pipefd[0]` *to `0`* for the right process. The second argument to `dup2` should be always 0 or 1. **3** If you have more than 2 members in the pipeline, those in the middle will need to `dup2` both the standard input and the standard output.

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist - This is actually a remnant from a previous version of the function. My command line is splitted on the '|' and pos is an index used to iterate over the resulting array of strings. It would make more sens to put it as a local variable of the function, indeed.